# How to get File Name without extension in Camel

Tags: apache-camel

Hi Does anyone know how to get a file name without extension in camel. using spring xml.

I know ${header.CamelFileNameOnly} will give the full file name like "test.txt".

I would just like to get the name "test" and need to use this name in somewhere else, does anyone know how to do it ?

Answer (score 8):

Use the [file-expression](http://camel.apache.org/file-language.html) language. Your route shall be something like

```
<camel:route>
    <camel:from uri="file://input/orders" />
    <camel:setHeader headerName="FileNameWithoutExtension">
        <camel:simple>${file:onlyname.noext}</camel:simple>
    </camel:setHeader>
</camel:route>
```

Answer (score 4):

See the Camel documentation

- http://camel.apache.org/file-language.html

You can then do use simple language (http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) to grab the only the name part using `${file:onlyname.noext}`